# How to limit memory per thread to avoid CPU to use pagefile memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

I would like to know is there a way to limit the memory per thread so that when the memory being used by all the existing processes exceeds the available RAM, the operating system will not moves virtual address spaces to the computer’s hard disk but instead it will wait for other thread ended and free the memory then only another thread will start. The reason to do this is when computer start using the page file it will largely slow down the whole process and it runs even slower than a single thread process.

Comment: What you're asking would be very difficult, if at all possible. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: If you don't want to use the page file then just set the page file size to zero. This is in the vast majority of scenarios a terrible idea, but you can do it if you really want to.

Comment: Hi, I am writing a floor detailing application. The floor number may be vary from one floor to 40 floor. I will generate floor detailing for each floor and then save it to a file. Since each floor detailing is independent to each other so I could utilize all the cores by parallel processing. I compare the time with parallel processing and non-processing but what I get is the time for parallel processing is longer than non-parallel processing. At the end I only figure out it is due to the reason where the existing processes exceeds the available RAM and CPU started to write to pagefile.

Comment: (assuming you've measured everything and found that page fault perf counter actually shows too high value) - buying a bit more RAM may be easiest solution (16GB cost under 100$... ) rather than trying to find some insane restrictions...

Comment: Hi, I have already using 16GB memory. Can you suggest me any other solution? Thanks!

Comment: Put the pagefile on an SSD.

Comment: ..or redesign your app so that a small threadpool processes the floors in parallel, but the degree is limited so that the current set of floors fits into the available RAM.

Comment: ..or redesign your app so that it creates a blocking pool queue of Floor classes at startup that just fits into the available RAM.  Have each processing thread extract a Floor instance from the pool, use it to process a floor/file, then return it to the pool.  Any thread that needs a Floor when the pool is empty then waits on the pool until a Floor becomes free.

Comment: ..or redesign your app so that each thread must obtain a 'floor token' from a semaphore before processing its floor, and return it when done.  Initialize the semaphore to some RAM-dependent limiting value.

Comment: How many cores do you have ? What the threads are doing ? Are they waiting for disk IO ? Take into account that if you have too many threads you loose time on thread switching and you can end up with worse overall performance then with less threads.

Comment: Is your goal to make it multithreaded or faster? Did you actually figured out what resource limits performance of your application (CPU/RAM/Disk IO/Network IO)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "per-thread" memory limits in .Net applications since memory is allocated from shared pool (per AppDomain).

I also believe there is no such restriction for native processes (essentially for the same reason - memory normally not tagged by the system with thread which allocated the memory).

Comment: Well, a Job Object, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161(VS.85).aspx, will let you set memory limits for a group of processes.

Comment: @JimMischel, maybe useful in general... but definitely not in sense of original question "limit memory usage per thread inside process" is way more granular than "limit memory usage for group of processes".